# Add repeated-measures column names as prefix instead of suffix using reshape

Tags: r, reshape

I am using the reshape function in base R to turn a long-format dataframe for a repeated measures design into a wide-format. See the toy dataset below. Questions 1,2, and 3 are individual responses on a three-item survey. There are four participants who each take the survey four times.

```
Q1 <- c(2,6,5,4,3,8,9,2,1,5,4,7,3,7,2,1)
Q2 <- c(4,7,6,3,1,2,5,6,7,5,4,3,5,6,6,3)
Q3 <- c(7,9,3,1,5,3,7,5,3,3,5,7,8,9,9,3)
Participant <- rep(c("Bob","Sue","Jim","Tom"), times = 1, each = 4)
Time <- rep(c("FirstSurvey","SecondSurvey","ThirdSurvey","FourthSurvey"), times = 4)

m <- as.data.frame(cbind(Participant, Time, Q1, Q2, Q3))
```

This yields the following dataframe

```
m

   Participant         Time Q1 Q2 Q3
1          Bob  FirstSurvey  2  4  7
2          Bob SecondSurvey  6  7  9
3          Bob  ThirdSurvey  5  6  3
4          Bob FourthSurvey  4  3  1
5          Sue  FirstSurvey  3  1  5
6          Sue SecondSurvey  8  2  3
7          Sue  ThirdSurvey  9  5  7
8          Sue FourthSurvey  2  6  5
9          Jim  FirstSurvey  1  7  3
10         Jim SecondSurvey  5  5  3
11         Jim  ThirdSurvey  4  4  5
12         Jim FourthSurvey  7  3  7
13         Tom  FirstSurvey  3  5  8
14         Tom SecondSurvey  7  6  9
15         Tom  ThirdSurvey  2  6  9
16         Tom FourthSurvey  1  3  3
```

If you then reshape it thus:

```
mReshaped <- reshape(m, idvar = "Participant", timevar = "Time", direction = "wide", sep = "", new.row.names = c(1,2,3,4))
```

it yields the following wide-format dataframe:

```
mReshaped

  Participant Q1FirstSurvey Q2FirstSurvey Q3FirstSurvey Q1SecondSurvey Q2SecondSurvey
1         Bob             2             4             7              6              7
2         Sue             3             1             5              8              2
3         Jim             1             7             3              5              5
4         Tom             3             5             8              7              6
  Q3SecondSurvey Q1ThirdSurvey Q2ThirdSurvey Q3ThirdSurvey Q1FourthSurvey Q2FourthSurvey
1              9             5             6             3              4              3
2              3             9             5             7              2              6
3              3             4             4             5              7              3
4              9             2             6             9              1              3
  Q3FourthSurvey
1              1
2              5
3              7
4              3
```

With the following column names

```
colnames(mReshaped)

 [1] "Participant"    "Q1FirstSurvey"  "Q2FirstSurvey"  "Q3FirstSurvey"  "Q1SecondSurvey"
 [6] "Q2SecondSurvey" "Q3SecondSurvey" "Q1ThirdSurvey"  "Q2ThirdSurvey"  "Q3ThirdSurvey" 
[11] "Q1FourthSurvey" "Q2FourthSurvey" "Q3FourthSurvey"
```

As you can see when the dataframe is reshaped the reshape function adds the time variable as a suffix to the column name for each repeated measure.

Does anyone know if there is an argument in the reshape function to allow you to choose to put the Time variable as prefix, *in front* of each Value variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you can change the order within `reshape`, but you can change it afterwards using `gsub` with a Regular Expression:

```
names(mReshaped) = gsub("(Q[0-9])(.*)", "\\2\\1", names(mReshaped))

 [1] "Participant"    "FirstSurveyQ1"  "FirstSurveyQ2"  "FirstSurveyQ3"  "SecondSurveyQ1"
 [6] "SecondSurveyQ2" "SecondSurveyQ3" "ThirdSurveyQ1"  "ThirdSurveyQ2"  "ThirdSurveyQ3" 
[11] "FourthSurveyQ1" "FourthSurveyQ2" "FourthSurveyQ3"
```

**UPDATE:** Explanation of how the code works: The code uses a Regular Expression (or "regex" for short), which is a text processing language that's very cryptic the first time you see it.

In this case `Q[0-9]` means match a "Q" followed by any digit. `(Q[0-9])` turns that match into a "capture group" meaning we can refer back to it later. This is capture group #1.

`.*` means match all remaining characters (anything that comes after whatever is matched by `Q[0-9]`). `.` means match any single character; adding `*` means match any string of characters of any length. `(.*)` turns the match into capture group #2.

`\\2\\1` takes the two strings we captured and reverses their order.

Regular expressions can be very useful for text manipulation tasks like this. A few places to learn more about them are [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), [here](http://stat545-ubc.github.io/block022_regular-expression.html), and [here](http://www.regexr.com/)

Comment: thanks that worked really well but I don't really understand how it worked. What do the (.*) and "//2//1" arguments do for example.

Comment: I found it hard to adapt your answer to the column names from my actual data. Is there any way for example to remove the final two characters, which are the timecode variable names (in my case a letter and a number (B1, B2, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9)) from every column name and add them as a prefix?

Comment: If you want to get rid of the last two characters, and they are always a capital letter followed  by one digit, then the following should work: `gsub("(Q[0-9])(.*)([A-Z][0-9])$", "\\3\\2\\1", names(mReshaped)). Note that we matched and captured the last two characters with `([A-Z][0-9])$`, meaning any capital letter followed by any digit. The `$` means those last two characters must be the end of the string. We put them in a third capture group and put that first in the substitution string. Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you. But I can't seem to get the script you sent to work. I created a vector: varNom <- c("firstwordB1", "secondwordB2", "thirdwordT1", "fourthwordT2", "fifthwordT3", "sixthwordT4", "seventhwordT5"). Then I applied your code substituting in the vector name like so: names(varNom) <- gsub("(Q[0-9])(.*)([A-Z][0-9])$", "\\3\\2\\1",  names(varNom)). I got the following error message: Error: unexpected symbol in "names(varNom) <- gsub("(Q[0-9])(.*)([A-Z][0-9])$", "\\3\\2\\1",  names(varNom))."

Comment: `varNom` is a vector of strings, not the column names of a data frame. So if you want to alter those strings, you would do this: `gsub("(Q[0-9])(.*)([A-Z][0-9])$", "\\3\\2\\1", varNom)`. However, my code was predicated on their being three sub-strings that needed to be rearranged, and I see only two in `varNom`. For example, if you want to turn `secondwordB2` into `B2secondword`, etc. Then you want: `gsub("(.*)([A-Z][0-9])$", "\\2\\1", varNom)`.

Comment: Ah I see. I found another (slightly longer) way around using your second recommendation. I turned the relevant columns names into a vector using colnames and then transformed them using your code, then added them back in using setnames. Though it was three lines of code instead of your elegant single line it still worked. So thank you!